# Show customer id in header.tpl on Opencart 2

Tags: opencart, opencart2.x, opencart-module

How to display customer id in header.tpl on Opencart 2?

```
    if ($this->customer->isLogged()) {
    $data['customer_id'] = $this->customer->getId(); // customer ID
    $data['customer_fname'] = $this->customer->getFirstName(); // customer email
    }
```

doesn`t work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In header.php file add this two variables

```
if ($this->customer->isLogged()) { // <-- This line is around 52
    $this->load->model('account/wishlist');

    $data['text_wishlist'] = sprintf($this->language->get('text_wishlist'), $this->model_account_wishlist->getTotalWishlist());
    $data['customer_id'] = $this->customer->getId(); // <-- add this variable
    $data['customer_fname'] = $this->customer->getFirstName(); // <-- and this variable
} else {
    $data['text_wishlist'] = sprintf($this->language->get('text_wishlist'), (isset($this->session->data['wishlist']) ? count($this->session->data['wishlist']) : 0));
}
```

In header.tpl file you can use the variables like this, must be inside the `if ($logged)` block

```
<?php if ($logged) { ?>
<?php echo $customer_id; ?>
<?php echo $customer_fname; ?>
<?php } ?>
```

Tested on OC 2.2.0.0